# Optimizing Large INSERT SELECT Transaction with 500k Records in Java and DB2

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, db2

I have a Java and Spring boot application that connects to a DB2 database. I'm executing an INSERT with the results of a SELECT using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` like this:

```
namedJdbcTemplate.execute("INSERT INTO tableA ... SELECT ... FROM tableB", inputParams, (PreparedStatementCallback<Integer>) ps -> ps.executeUpdate());
```

The problem is that this is taking too long because SELECT retrieves more than 500k rows. Is there a way to optimize this?

It's worth to mention that my SELECT has some TRIMs and joins I need.
Thanks in advance

Comment: *this is taking too long because SELECT retrieves more than 500k rows.* Retrieve fewer rows. Create a materialized view and select from that. But you can't optimize away writing half a million records.

Comment: Did you calculate the size (in megabytes/gigabytes etc) of the data to be inserted? If you are doing this under transaction control then the logging overhead is significant.  Did you consider using an unlogged transaction instead? Doing bulk actions is considerably faster when unlogged although other factors come into play depending on your HA solution.

Answer (score 0):

well beside the improvements you might do to your query or your java code that we don't see here
Could you check : JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate and SpringBatch and see if it makes it faster and fits your need ( i never used them tho ,but i guess they may be helpful in your case)
And try to optimize the query as much as possible
and if you want something that has a specific filter then don't retrieve all the 500k rows , instead filter the select by those values first